# How to use the HM-11 for YUV to HEVC encoding?

Tags: video, encode, hevc

Hi every body I'm using HM-11 to encode YUV video in HEVC streams but I am having 3 problems:

1. When I set the frame size to 720x1280, the ffplay of ffmpeg shows no a too blurred video. One while with cif format (352x288) I can view it. What else do I have to set up to be able to view it.
2. I’am gettingthis warning :

   ```
   HM software: Encoder Version [11.0][Windows][VS 1600][32 bit]
   ******************************************************************
   ** WARNING: --SEIDecodedPictureHash is now disabled by default. **
   **          Automatic verification of decoded pictures by a     **
   **          decoder requires this option to be enabled.         **
   ******************************************************************

   Error: found fewer Reference Picture Sets than GOPSize
   Error: Invalid GOP structure given
   ```

   What does that mean and how can I avoid this warning?
3. The last is the one above about the GOP size, how can I variate it?

Comment: What configuration file are you using?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your configuration file is not set up properly.

Let's take the example of the *encoder_randomaccess_main.cfg* which is provided with HM in the *cfg/* directory.

First lines are about *File I/O*:

```
#======== File I/O =====================
BitstreamFile                 : str.bin
ReconFile                     : rec.yuv
```

I generally replace this by:

```
#======== File I/O ===============
InputFile                     : your_video.yuv
InputBitDepth                 : 8           # Input bitdepth
FrameRate                     : 24          # Frame Rate per second
FrameSkip                     : 0           # Number of frames to be skipped in input
SourceWidth                   : 416         # Input  frame width
SourceHeight                  : 240         # Input  frame height
FramesToBeEncoded              : 100         # Number of frames to be coded

BitstreamFile                 : your_video.bin
ReconFile                     : rec.yuv
```

1. Here the `SourceWidth` and `SourceHeight` have to be set according to your input video.
2. It seems the encoder finds the GOP structure given in your configuration file invalid. This can have different reasons. Either the GOP structure given in the configuration file under the section `coding structure` is indeed invalid. Or this might be linked to the first problem you have (other erroneous configuration parameters).
3. You can change the GOP structure in the configuration file under the section `coding structure`. Here, I would suggest that you read the documentation given in HM in the *doc/* directory. There is a good explanation about the GOP structure in *software_manual.pdf*.

As an example, here is the GOP structure given in the default file *encoder_randomaccess_main.cfg*

```
#======== Coding Structure =============
IntraPeriod                   : 32          # Period of I-Frame ( -1 = only first)
DecodingRefreshType           : 1           # Random Accesss 0:none, 1:CRA, 2:IDR, 3:Recovery Point SEI
GOPSize                       : 8           # GOP Size (number of B slice = GOPSize-1)
#        Type POC QPoffset QPfactor tcOffsetDiv2 betaOffsetDiv2 temporal_id #ref_pics_active #ref_pics reference pictures     predict deltaRPS #ref_idcs reference idcs 
Frame1:  B    8   1        0.442    0            0              0           2                3         -8 -12 -16             0
Frame2:  B    4   2        0.3536   0            0              1           2                3         -4  -8   4             1       4        4         1 1 0 1
Frame3:  B    2   3        0.3536   0            0              2           2                4         -2  -6   2 6           1       2        4         1 1 1 1
Frame4:  B    1   4        0.68     0            0              3           2                4         -1   1   3 7           1       1        5         1 0 1 1 1
Frame5:  B    3   4        0.68     0            0              3           2                4         -1  -3   1 5           1      -2        5         1 1 1 1 0
Frame6:  B    6   3        0.3536   0            0              2           2                3         -2  -6   2             1      -3        5         0 1 1 1 0
Frame7:  B    5   4        0.68     0            0              3           2                4         -1  -5   1 3           1       1        4         1 1 1 1
Frame8:  B    7   4        0.68     0            0              3           2                4         -1  -3  -7 1           1      -2        5         1 1 1 1 0
```

Comment: Thanks alot damjeux for the answer. I afterwaerds myself understood that it was a problem of the input yuv video I was using which was a cif. Now I have another question what is the most fit for hevc coding among the config files because that's the one i need to use.

Comment: It depends on your target application. If you are targeting "real-time" streaming (such as video conferencing), then low-delay makes most sense. If you are targeting video-on-demand on a website, then random-access makes more sense.